# How to verify if two strings are key pairs generated using ssh-keygen?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a private key generated with `ssh-keygen` and a list of public keys. I want to find out if one of the public keys is the public pair of the private key. Is it possible to compare a private/public key pair using the CLI to see if they match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract the public key out of the private key with

```
ssh-keygen -y

-y      This option will read a private OpenSSH format file and print an
        OpenSSH public key to stdout.
```

Example:

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f my_file
AAAAB3N...
```

You can grep for parts of this extracted key in your list of public keys to find the correct one, if needed.